# PHP Variable null despite setting to non-null value

Tags: php, wordpress, file, variables, null

```
//  POST -- PARSE / PROCESSING
if (!empty($_POST)):
    global $rjw_file = $_FILES["rjw_settings"]["name"]["rjw_file_src"] or die();
endif;

function rjw_settings_section_callback(  ) { 
    //  Display text if WooCommerce is disabled.
    if ( !in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins'))))
        echo "Please Activate WooCommerce";

    print_r($_POST);
    echo ("<br/><br/><br/>");
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo("<br/><br/><br/>");
    print_r($rjw_file);
}
function rjw_options_page(  ) { 

    ?>
    <form action="" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <h2>CSV Stock Import</h2>

        <?php
        settings_fields( 'pluginPage' );
        do_settings_sections( 'pluginPage' );
        submit_button();
        ?>

    </form>
    <?php

}
```

So in the above, $_FILES prints a populated array. Setting the variable doesn't
cause the script to die, as using ["rjw_file_src"]["name"] does.
Still, rjw_file is always null and never printed (and var_dump states NULL)
Is there a way to rectify this? I'm planning on processing a CSV file
and deleting once I'm done so it doesn't need to be a permanent upload I just
need access to the contents. Right now I can't even get a name lol - despite
it being printed to the screen just fine.

Array returned by $_FILES:

```
Array ( [rjw_settings] => 
    Array ( 
        [name] => Array ( [rjw_file_src] => Ayk_beN5.jpeg )
        [type] => Array ( [rjw_file_src] => image/jpeg )
        [tmp_name] => Array ( [rjw_file_src] => /tmp/phpio5xgf )
        [error] => Array ( [rjw_file_src] => 0 )
        [size] => Array ( [rjw_file_src] => 7691 ) 
    ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misused the **global** keyword. It should be used inside functions to access global variables. So this is how it should be done:

```
//  POST -- PARSE / PROCESSING
if (!empty($_POST)):
    $rjw_file = $_FILES["rjw_settings"]["name"]["rjw_file_src"] or die();
endif;

function rjw_settings_section_callback(  ) {
    global $rjw_file;
    //  Display text if WooCommerce is disabled.
    if ( !in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins'))))
        echo "Please Activate WooCommerce";

    print_r($_POST);
    echo ("<br/><br/><br/>");
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo("<br/><br/><br/>");
    print_r($rjw_file);
}
```

Comment: I've completely restructured it. For whatever reason wordpress was getting weird when I used a blank action value, but with default value it was buggy. Basically, I can't seem to use files with wordpress. So I've enabled WooCommerce REST API and letting the user paste CSV into a textbox to be processed into products (admin only space)

It'd be nice if they could just upload a .csv value and I parse it but when I tried to move_uploaded_file it just copied my plugin's php file to the uploads folder. So for now I just have a textarea with maxlength of 1,048,527 for ~2000 products worth of space